# UITextView increases text size after modal segue

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview, font-size

I have the `UITableView` (1). From there I can click on a cell to get to `UITableView` (2, modal segue), where a `UITextField` automatically gets activated for text input. When I now close this modal called `UITableView` and go to the other, normal pushed `UITableView` (3), the text inside the cell (in a `UITextView`) is strongly increased. I go back and in one more time and the text size is normal (Helvetica, 11pt) again.

It seems only to appear when the `UITableView` (2) is called before. How can I fix this issue?